Not able to accept LSP response
I started using lsp-zero for my Neovim but I am not able to accept the responses that it gives. I am able to see the suggestions, definitions, etc. perfectly. I am able to use the up and down arrow to move through the LSP suggestions dropdown. But I am not able to accept it.
Here is my lsp_config file. Please check and share how I can improve this.
Ideally I would like to press Enter and accept the LSP.

I am also facing the same problem and will love any lead on how to solve it

It would be nice to embed your code with appropriate style on your post for better response.

If you're using lsp-zero you might wanna give this a try if you haven't yet.
https://lsp-zero.netlify.app/docs/autocomplete.html#use-enter-to-confirm-completion
In essence, by default the selections from the suggested dropdowns can be confirmed using <C-y>, but you can also map something like Enter (<CR>) to it, using custom mappings.
I'm not entirely certain how the integration of below would look in your linked config,  so here's just an example from my own .config/nvim/after/plugin/lsp.lua file
local cmp = require('cmp')

cmp.setup({
  -- There may be other settings in your setup too,  
  -- but below is what offers the custom mapping
  mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.insert({
      ['<CR>'] = cmp.mapping.confirm({select = true}),
  }),
})

The mapping section above e.g. just binds Enter to confirm the top suggested entry without having to select it. Likewise, setting it to false would simply mean you'd have to choose an entry in the list before being able to confirm using Enter.
I can at least confirm this to be working on my setup, also together with lsp-zero
